# Install i386 printer driver on an amd64 system?

Tags: 11.04, 64-bit, printing, canon

According to [this topic](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8308515#post8308515), it's possible to install these i386-drivers for my Pixma MP560 printer on an amd64 Ubuntu. Unfortunately, I cannot install the drivers:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture cnijfilter-common_3.20-1_i386.deb
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 package architecture (i386) does not match system (amd64)
(Reading database ... 151200 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace cnijfilter-common:i386 3.20-1 (using cnijfilter-common_3.20-  1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement cnijfilter-common:i386 ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cnijfilter-common:i386:
 cnijfilter-common:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.4-1).
 cnijfilter-common:i386 depends on libcupsys2 (>= 1.2.1) | libcups2.
 cnijfilter-common:i386 depends on libpopt0 (>= 1.7).
dpkg: error processing cnijfilter-common:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cnijfilter-common:i386
```

The packages `libc6`, `libcups2`, and `libpopt0` are installed on my system, but `libcupsys2`. But `libcupsys2` is a virtual package since Ubuntu 7.04 and many users got the printer running under Ubuntu 10.10.

I'm on the 64 bit version of Ubuntu 11.04.

Any ideas?

Comment: were you following post #112?   A guy below that said by following #112 it was working on Natty.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, this question is a bit old, but since I just bumped into the same thing, I'll post what solved it for me anyway:

I found the solution here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/701856/comments/20

```
Create a directory.
move the .deb files into the directory
open a shell
change dir into the directory

For each package do the following:

1. dpkg -x [package].deb common
2. dpkg --control [package].deb
3. vim DEBIAN/control
4. remove troublesome dependencies from the "Dependency: libc (..." line (or delete it -- move to line than press 'dd' than ESC:x)
5. cp -a DEBIAN/ common/
6. dpkg -b common [package].deb
7. dpkg -i [package].deb
8. rm -rf common DEBIAN
```

The procedure might seem complicated at first, but actually it is not. The step-by-step instructions are very easy and clear. I got my Brother HL-2250DN working this way.

Comment: The directory in which all this is done has to have 755 permissions, so it would be prudent to run `chmod 755 . -R`.

Comment: @Wolter Hellmund When should chmod 755 . -R be run?

Comment: You can find a good explanation at http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Answer (score 1):

you can find the modified deb files here 
http://play.oob.gr/files/common.deb 
http://play.oob.gr/files/mx870.deb

install with --force-architecture

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the posts on reference:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1264928&page=13

HTH